# org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException

Tags: java, solr

In my java program(QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);) I got Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Point must be in 'lat, lon' or 'x y' format: amazon.com . I don't understand the mistake i did here.

Code:

```
 public class Get {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException {
        HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr");

        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery("sony digital camera");
        query.addFilterQuery("cat:electronics","store:amazon.com");
        query.setFields("id","price","merchant","cat","store");
        query.setStart(0);    
        query.set("defType", "edismax");

        QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
        SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
          System.out.println(results.get(i));
        }
      }
}
```

Anobody please Help...Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're adding a filter for the field `store`, which if you're experimenting with the example from the `example/` directory in the Solr distribution, is defined with a `location` field type. The location field type as defined in the example requires a position, expressed in latitude and longitude. When you're adding a filter query for that field looking for the text `amazon.com` (as you do with `store:amazon.com`), the types doesn't match. The field expects values in `latitude,longitude` pairs, while you're trying to filter it by a `string`.

From the example `schema.xml`:

```
<field name="store" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

[...]

<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
```

If you want to use a single string you can change the field type of the field `store` to be `string` instead.